# L pode ser semivogal?

Tags: fonética, semivogal

Estava estudando semivogais e o professor anotou apenas duas vogais em *Leal*. Entretanto, pensei que o último L seria uma semivogal.

O L em *Leal* não seria uma semivogal porque a pronúncia do L com som de U é algo particular da pronúncia brasileira em algumas regiões?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A questão principal é que, tecnicamente, as **letras** não são nem consoantes nem vogais! Sons, sim, podem ser classificados desta forma!

Antigamente, o /l/ final passou a ser velarizado, o que significa que, de uma forma específica, ele foi indo para trás na boca, tornando-se um [ɫ]. Em Portugal, este som é assim até hoje, porém, no Brasil, este processo continuou e se tornou totalmente velarizado, um [w], mas que ainda é representado na escrita com a letra < l >. Então, em dialetos brasileiros (na grande maioria), a letra L representa uma semivogal.

Assim, uma transcrição fonética da palavra "leal" em grande parte dos dialetos europeu e brasileiros fica:

• Portugal: [liˈaɫ]

• Brasil: [leˈaw]

Comment: Aprendi algo novo com sua resposta (que a definição fundamental de vogal/consoante é fonética). Obrigado!